# Where I find my Connection String to automate SAP through in C# application?

Tags: c#, sap-gui

In "My Connection string" in code below, what should I mention? Where shall I find connection string in SAP.

In my system I am having SAP Logon Pad.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SAPActive.openSAP("my connection string");
        SAPActive.login("10", "jdoe", "password", "EN");
        SAPActive.SapSession.StartTransaction("VA03");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have SAP Logon/SAP GUI to log in the concerned SAP system or how do you access it manually? These Web pages may also help you: https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752/7.52.5/en-US?q=Route%20strings and also https://www.google.ie/search?q=connection+route+string%20site:sap.com (NB: connection string is also known as route string)

Comment: Ya in my system am having SAP logon pad. From that how I find connection string in SAP logon pad.

Comment: What I need to mention in SAPActive.openSAP(????).

Comment: I added an answer to show you the details. You should add in your question a screenshot of your logon pad if you need a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string can be deduced from what you can see in your SAP Logon or in your SAP Logon Pad.

For instance, say you have these connection entries in your SAP Logon (Pad):
[image]

Because they refer to a server/host and an instance number, the corresponding Connection Strings are, respectively:

- `/H/127.0.0.2/S/sapdp00`
- `/H/127.0.0.1/S/sapdp00`

If the connection entry refers to a logon group and a message server (and a router), the things get more complex. Paste a screenshot of your connection entry if you need assistance.

You may also find the file containing all the entries in XML format:

- Go to the Options: 
  [image]
- Go to the menu SAP Logon Pad Options > Local Configuration Files and double-click the "Local File" 
  [image]
- It opens the file `SAPUILandscape.xml` 
  [image: SAPUILandscape.xml]

For more information, see the [SAP Library](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752/latest/en-US?q=Route%20strings) (free access) or [SAP note 103019 - SAPshortcut: Program parameters](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/103019/E) (access needs SAP client authentication).

Comment: I checked in my SAP logon Pad under Group server its sowing as Public and Message server under some address is there.. For Example rr.server.xx.com.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot in your question? Thanks.

Comment: Name under NPL is not visible in my SAP logon pad